# Show combinatorially that $S(n+1, k) = \binom n0 S(0,k-1) + \binom n1 S(1,k-1) + \cdots + \binom nn S(n,k-1)$

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to show combinatorially that 
$$S(n+1, k) = \binom n0 S(0,k-1) + \binom n1 S(1,k-1) + \cdots + \binom nn S(n,k-1),$$
where $S(n,k)$ represents the Stirling number of the second kind. I've received the hint that I should first find a combinatorial argument to show that
$$\binom {n+1}k = \binom 0{k-1} + \binom 1{k-1} + \cdots + \binom n{k-1},$$ 
but I can only find an algebraic proof using several iterations of
$$\binom {n+1}k = \binom nk + \binom n{k-1}.$$
Could someone please point me in the direction for how I should be thinking about these problems?

Comment: I'm gueesing that by $S(n+1,k)$ you mean a Stirling number of the second kind. I would make that explicit.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Writing your identity as a sum, you have then $$S_{n+1,k}=\sum _{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}S_{i,k-1}=S_{n+1,k}=\sum _{i=0}^n\binom{n}{n-i}S_{n-i,k-1}=\sum _{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}S_{n-i,k-1}.$$
Where the last two steps are just using binomial symmetry and a change of variable. Now, S_{n,k} are the number of ways to partition $\{1,2,\cdots, n\}$ into $k$ disjoint non-empty blocks. Hence what if you choose the elements that are going to be in the block of $n+1$ and partition the rest in $k-1$ blocks?